# How to make MongoDB's mongorestore update and replace files with the same _id

Tags: linux, mongodb, database-migration, database

So we've recently setup sharding and we're migrating some of the data from several clients across several smaller databases into a bigger, sharded one. The problem is, that if I try to move data from production and do a **mongorestore**, then the files won't update if they have the same **_id**. This is a problem, because several mongorestores might be necessary as we test the sharded database and as customer production data changes over the testing period.

I obviously don't want to use **--drop**, since that will drop the whole collection instead of replacing the old files. Is there any way of doing this properly?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, although not ideal.

I'll use **mongoimport** with the **--upsert** option, instead of **mongodump**. For a whole database, I might need to write a script to mimic mongodump, but oh well.